# Getting Events from Calendar using C# and Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to develop a console app to list, remove and add events to a specific user's calendar.  I'm developing a business process.  I'm starting by listing events.

```
Calendar cal =
    client
    .Users["UserName@CompanyName.com"]
    .Calendars["AAMkAGIzZDM4O...."]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync()
    .Result;
```

I get the correct calendar back but the Events collection is null.  There are 13 events in the calendar.  I have Calendar Read/Write permissions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an environment to test the c# Graph SDK, but I suspect the underlying query doesn't ask Graph for the calendar events so that's why the field is null.

Using Graph explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#), we can try an equivalent query and note only metadata about the calendars are returned.

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars`

[image]

The Graph explorer has some calendar sample queries. They might not be visible by default, so click the 'show more samples' link.

[image]

The `all events in my calendar` sample query is probably what you're looking for.  The request is:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$select=subject,body,bodyPreview,organizer,attendees,start,end,location`

(or /calendars/{calendar-id}/events if you want events for a specific calendar)

The next step is converting this REST API query into the SDK syntax to use in your application.

From [this sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/blob/5397a8360a358fe7d0081f5ca221b75fde6414e8/Graph-ASPNET-46-Snippets/Microsoft%20Graph%20ASPNET%20Snippets/Models/EventsService.cs#L24), a starting point is:

```
IUserEventsCollectionPage events = await graphClient.Me.Events.Request().GetAsync();
```

Besides querying the events, you might also want to look into [querying the users calendar view](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/blob/5397a8360a358fe7d0081f5ca221b75fde6414e8/Graph-ASPNET-46-Snippets/Microsoft%20Graph%20ASPNET%20Snippets/Models/EventsService.cs#L51) which allows you to specify a start and end date.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting here that `Calendars["..."].Events` will only give you event masters.

An alternative is to use `Calendars["..."].CalendarView` with query options of "startDateTime" and "endDateTime" which will give you all the event instances in that time frame.

Answer (score 0):

Dan, thanks for the post.  I realized my mistake after reading your post.  Here is the code that works:

```
            string userEmail = "UserName@CompanyName.com";
            string calId = "AAMkAGIzZDM4OWI0LWN...….";

            ICalendarEventsCollectionPage events = client.Users[$"{userEmail}"]
                .Calendars[$"{calId}"]
                .Events.Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

Comment: I modified my code per Dan's suggestion and added Events after selecting calendar.  I've shown code in above post.  Really simple fix.