# C# Microsoft Graph API obtain specific calendar

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm using the new Microsoft Graph Core API `v1.20.0` in a Visual Studio 2019 `v16.4.5` C# project.
I want to obtain all calendar entries (`Event`s) of each office365 calendar separately.

So far I know, I can retrieve all calendars with `await graphClient.Me.Calendars.Request().GetAsync();` and Events with

```
string startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("s");
string endDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).ToString("s");
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("startDateTime", startDate),
    new QueryOption("endDateTime", endDate),
};

var resultPage = await graphClient.Me.Events.Request(queryOptions)
    .OrderBy("createdDateTime DESC")
    .GetAsync();
```

But I don't know how to iterate over all Calendars and obtaining all Events for each Calendar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Events from Calendar using C# and Microsoft Graph SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52693341/getting-events-from-calendar-using-c-sharp-and-microsoft-graph-sdk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me.Events will just return events from the main calendar for a User.

You will need to use Me.Calendars first as documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

```
var calendars = await graphClient.Me.Calendars
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

and for each calendar id you get back call list events https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

```
GET /me/calendars/{id}/events
```

which in the SDK would be

```
graphClient.Me.Calendars["calendar-id"].Events..Request()
        .GetAsync();
```